# Sent JSON data to DJANGO. Now I can't get it back

Tags: jquery, python, django

Good day. 
I sent JSON data to my server (js to Django) and in the server, I just saved the data (still in JSON format) directly to the database without converting it to string. 
Now I want to retrieve that same data but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/submitdata/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data:  JSON.stringify(userdata),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (){
             alert('success');
   },
   error: function (){
           alert('sorry, an error occurred');
```

)};

And in the server

```
def submitdata(request):
      if request.is_ajax():
          if request.method == 'POST':
              save_data = my_model(username='michael', userdata = request.body)
              save_data.save()
```

It worked fine. It got saved into the database. 
The problem I have now is retrieving it. 
I tried this: 
In my client

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/getdata/',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { user_name: 'michael' },
   success: function (result){
   JSON.parse(result);
   },
   error: function (){}
   )};
```

And in my server

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_name = request.POST['user_name']
    datum = my_model.objects.get(username=user_name)
    return HttpResponse(datum)
```

It doesn't work. It gives me an error: 
Unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of JSON data

Note: I tried to use JSON.parse on the returning data

Comment: So the error comes from the JS? IIUC, why don't you `json.dumps(datum)` before sending it back?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonResponse(datum.userdata)` instead of `HttpResponse` if you do this, you don't need to parse the result.